# connect express js to multiple db (mongo, mysql and neo4j)

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, express, neo4j

A newbie question: I am trying to make an API server using express js. But dont know how to implement connecting to multiple dbs simultaneously  like mongodb, mysql and neo4j.

Lets say a call to :

localhost/api/mongodb connects to mongodb
localhost/api/neo4j connects to neo4j
localhost/api/mysql connects to mysql

I am able to connect to each db separately like mongodb using mongoose and so on, but is it possible to make separate calls to each db and perform CRUD operations on them based upon POST/GET etc.

Comment: It is absolutely possible. You need to use different drivers like ``node-mysql`` or ``node-neo4j`` or ``mongojs`` on POST/GET call. Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Do you want to query them in parallel? Is there an order, so from the result of a query depends the following queries to other DBMS?